# Matrix exponent differentiation

Tags: matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Given $f(x) = x^T\exp(xx^T)x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, find the $\nabla_xf(x).$

Note: $\exp(A) = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{A^k}{k!}$, $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$

Comment: Please provide context for the question, it is the way it works: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - Show what you tried first. Can you for instance compute the differential for the map $f(x) = x^k$? For the map $f(x) = x^Tx$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $x^T(xx^T) ^kx=(x^Tx) ^{k+1}$. And $x^Tx$ is just a number, not a vector/matrix.

Comment: +1  which is an instance of Higham's fundamental law for matrix functions
$$
A,B\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times n}
 \quad\implies\quad ​f(AB^T)\;A = A\;f(B^TA)
$$
applied to vectors.